# Plot data in same column python

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization

I had a dataset with two features: Identification_person and Day. To count how many different an id appeared i did the following:

```
 dfc= df.groupby(['Identification_person']).Day.nunique()
```

And obtained:

```
  Identification_person
    1003412255        1
    1005776162        1
    10240210418296    1
    10240210425300    2
    10240210425301    2
    10240210425305    1
    10240210425306    1
```

The problem is that i can't make the "count" a column so i don't know how i can plot this. I wanted to plot in the x axis the person and in the y axis the amount of different days it appears.

Anyone know how to plot this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `reset_index()`

```
dfc= df.groupby(['Identification_person']).Day.nunique().reset_index()
```

and now you have a dataframe to play with either Pandas plotting function/matplotlib etc.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I have to wait a few minutes to accept the answer but don't worry because i will.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly plot the series. Try this!

```
df.groupby(['Identification_person']).Day.nunique().plot.bar()
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
series=pd.Series([1,2,4],index=['asdf','asdf','asdf'])
series.plot.bar() 
plt.ylabel('counts')
plt.show()
```

[image]